# Calculate difference between dates in hours with closest conditioned rows per group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, dplyr, data.table

I have the following sample dataframe called df (`dput` below):

```
   group                date indicator
1      A 2022-11-01 01:00:00     FALSE
2      A 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE
3      A 2022-11-01 04:00:00      TRUE
4      A 2022-11-01 05:00:00     FALSE
5      A 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE
6      A 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE
7      A 2022-11-01 10:00:00     FALSE
8      A 2022-11-01 12:00:00     FALSE
9      B 2022-11-01 01:00:00     FALSE
10     B 2022-11-01 02:00:00     FALSE
11     B 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE
12     B 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE
13     B 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE
14     B 2022-11-01 08:00:00     FALSE
15     B 2022-11-01 11:00:00      TRUE
16     B 2022-11-01 13:00:00     FALSE
```

I would like to calculate the difference in hours between dates with their nearest conditioned rows which have `indicator == TRUE` per group. Also, the rows with TRUE should return 0 as output. Here you can see the desired output called df_desired:

```
   group                date indicator diff_hours
1      A 2022-11-01 01:00:00     FALSE          3
2      A 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE          1
3      A 2022-11-01 04:00:00      TRUE          0
4      A 2022-11-01 05:00:00     FALSE          1
5      A 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE          0
6      A 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE          1
7      A 2022-11-01 10:00:00     FALSE          4
8      A 2022-11-01 12:00:00     FALSE          6
9      B 2022-11-01 01:00:00     FALSE          5
10     B 2022-11-01 02:00:00     FALSE          4
11     B 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE          3
12     B 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE          0
13     B 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE          1
14     B 2022-11-01 08:00:00     FALSE          2
15     B 2022-11-01 11:00:00      TRUE          0
16     B 2022-11-01 13:00:00     FALSE          2
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to calculate the difference between dates in hours with respect to their nearest conditioned row per group?

---

Here `dput` of df and df_desired:

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), date = structure(c(1667260800, 
1667268000, 1667271600, 1667275200, 1667278800, 1667282400, 1667293200, 
1667300400, 1667260800, 1667264400, 1667268000, 1667278800, 1667282400, 
1667286000, 1667296800, 1667304000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), indicator = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

df_desired <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), date = structure(c(1667260800, 
1667268000, 1667271600, 1667275200, 1667278800, 1667282400, 1667293200, 
1667300400, 1667260800, 1667264400, 1667268000, 1667278800, 1667282400, 
1667286000, 1667296800, 1667304000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), indicator = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE), diff_hours = c(3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 
0, 1, 2, 0, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `map_dbl`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(diff_hours = map_dbl(date, ~ min(abs(.x - date[indicator]))))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 16 × 4
# Groups:   group [2]
   group date                indicator diff_hours
   <chr> <dttm>              <lgl>          <dbl>
 1 A     2022-11-01 01:00:00 FALSE              3
 2 A     2022-11-01 03:00:00 FALSE              1
 3 A     2022-11-01 04:00:00 TRUE               0
 4 A     2022-11-01 05:00:00 FALSE              1
 5 A     2022-11-01 06:00:00 TRUE               0
 6 A     2022-11-01 07:00:00 FALSE              1
 7 A     2022-11-01 10:00:00 FALSE              4
 8 A     2022-11-01 12:00:00 FALSE              6
 9 B     2022-11-01 01:00:00 FALSE              5
10 B     2022-11-01 02:00:00 FALSE              4
11 B     2022-11-01 03:00:00 FALSE              3
12 B     2022-11-01 06:00:00 TRUE               0
13 B     2022-11-01 07:00:00 FALSE              1
14 B     2022-11-01 08:00:00 FALSE              2
15 B     2022-11-01 11:00:00 TRUE               0
16 B     2022-11-01 13:00:00 FALSE              2
```

---

If one wants to keep the original difference (not absolute):

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(diff_hours = map_dbl(date, ~ (.x - date[indicator])[which.min(abs(.x - date[indicator]))]))
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining this? Cant wrap my head around how it managed to grab the right indicator

Comment: Hi @Maël, thank you for your answer! Do you know if it is possible to make the `diff_hours` negative if the dates are before the nearest conditioned rows? So the first rows should in that case have -3 instead of 3. Do you know if that's easily possible with your code?

Comment: Sure! Just remove the abs function

Comment: Yes, I thought the same by removing the abs, but then I get some weird output like for example -7200 for row 3 and -5 for row 1 which should be -3. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: True, this is because the `min` function is looking for the minimum value, not the closest to 0. You can index on the absolute min with the original difference, check edit

Comment: @TomHoel Sure. So, the operation is done by group. For each `date`, we compute the difference of that date to every other date for whom `indicator` is TRUE (when indexing a logical vector with `[`, no need to state `== TRUE`, same as we don't do `mtcars[(mpg > 10) == TRUE)]`), then we get the absolute value of that difference, and choose the minimum.

Answer (score 6):

You can try `data.table` like below (there should be options more efficient than mine)

- Using `findInterval` or `roll = "nearest"`

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  diff_hours := abs(
    difftime(date,
      date[indicator][pmax(1, findInterval(date, date[indicator]))],
      units = "hours"
    )
  ),
  group
][]
```

or

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  diffhours := abs(
    difftime(date,
      .SD[indicator][.SD,
        date,
        by = group,
        on = "date",
        roll = "nearest",
        mult = "first"
      ][, date],
      units = "hours"
    )
  )
][]
```

which gives

```
    group                date indicator diff_hours
 1:     A 2022-11-01 01:00:00     FALSE    3 hours
 2:     A 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE    1 hours
 3:     A 2022-11-01 04:00:00      TRUE    0 hours
 4:     A 2022-11-01 05:00:00     FALSE    1 hours
 5:     A 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE    0 hours
 6:     A 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE    1 hours
 7:     A 2022-11-01 10:00:00     FALSE    4 hours
 8:     A 2022-11-01 12:00:00     FALSE    6 hours
 9:     B 2022-11-01 01:00:00     FALSE    5 hours
10:     B 2022-11-01 02:00:00     FALSE    4 hours
11:     B 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE    3 hours
12:     B 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE    0 hours
13:     B 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE    1 hours
14:     B 2022-11-01 08:00:00     FALSE    2 hours
15:     B 2022-11-01 11:00:00      TRUE    0 hours
16:     B 2022-11-01 13:00:00     FALSE    2 hours
```

- Using `outer` (not *efficient* due to the use of `apply`)

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  diff_hours := apply(abs(outer(date, date[indicator], `-`)), 1, min) / 3600,
  group
][]
```

and you will see

```
    group                date indicator diff_hours
 1:     A 2022-11-01 01:00:00     FALSE          3
 2:     A 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE          1
 3:     A 2022-11-01 04:00:00      TRUE          0
 4:     A 2022-11-01 05:00:00     FALSE          1
 5:     A 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE          0
 6:     A 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE          1
 7:     A 2022-11-01 10:00:00     FALSE          4
 8:     A 2022-11-01 12:00:00     FALSE          6
 9:     B 2022-11-01 01:00:00     FALSE          5
10:     B 2022-11-01 02:00:00     FALSE          4
11:     B 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE          3
12:     B 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE          0
13:     B 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE          1
14:     B 2022-11-01 08:00:00     FALSE          2
15:     B 2022-11-01 11:00:00      TRUE          0
16:     B 2022-11-01 13:00:00     FALSE          2
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few of the previous approaches in base R:

```r
#Maël answer in base R
by(df, df$group, \(d) transform(
  d, diff_hours = sapply(d$date, \(x) min(abs(x - d$date[d[["indicator"]]])))
  )) |>
  do.call(what = rbind.data.frame)
#>      group                date indicator diff_hours
#> A.1      A 2022-10-31 20:00:00     FALSE          3
#> A.2      A 2022-10-31 22:00:00     FALSE          1
#> A.3      A 2022-10-31 23:00:00      TRUE          0
#> A.4      A 2022-11-01 00:00:00     FALSE          1
#> A.5      A 2022-11-01 01:00:00      TRUE          0
#> A.6      A 2022-11-01 02:00:00     FALSE          1
#> A.7      A 2022-11-01 05:00:00     FALSE          4
#> A.8      A 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE          6
#> B.9      B 2022-10-31 20:00:00     FALSE          5
#> B.10     B 2022-10-31 21:00:00     FALSE          4
#> B.11     B 2022-10-31 22:00:00     FALSE          3
#> B.12     B 2022-11-01 01:00:00      TRUE          0
#> B.13     B 2022-11-01 02:00:00     FALSE          1
#> B.14     B 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE          2
#> B.15     B 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE          0
#> B.16     B 2022-11-01 08:00:00     FALSE          2

#ThomasIsCoding answer in base
transform(df, diff_hours = apply(abs(outer(df$date, df$date[df$indicator], `-`))/3600, 1, min))
#>    group                date indicator diff_hours
#> 1      A 2022-10-31 20:00:00     FALSE          3
#> 2      A 2022-10-31 22:00:00     FALSE          1
#> 3      A 2022-10-31 23:00:00      TRUE          0
#> 4      A 2022-11-01 00:00:00     FALSE          1
#> 5      A 2022-11-01 01:00:00      TRUE          0
#> 6      A 2022-11-01 02:00:00     FALSE          1
#> 7      A 2022-11-01 05:00:00     FALSE          1
#> 8      A 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE          1
#> 9      B 2022-10-31 20:00:00     FALSE          3
#> 10     B 2022-10-31 21:00:00     FALSE          2
#> 11     B 2022-10-31 22:00:00     FALSE          1
#> 12     B 2022-11-01 01:00:00      TRUE          0
#> 13     B 2022-11-01 02:00:00     FALSE          1
#> 14     B 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE          2
#> 15     B 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE          0
#> 16     B 2022-11-01 08:00:00     FALSE          2
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution based on `tidyr::fill()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  arrange(group, date) %>%
  mutate(
    ind_prev = if_else(indicator, date, as.POSIXct(NA)),
    ind_next = ind_prev
  ) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  fill(ind_prev, .direction = "down") %>%
  fill(ind_next, .direction = "up") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      ind_prev:ind_next,
      ~ abs(as.numeric(date - .x, unit = "hours"))
    ),
    diff_hours = pmin(ind_prev, ind_next, na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  select(!ind_prev:ind_next)
```

```
# A tibble: 16 × 4
   group date                indicator diff_hours
   <chr> <dttm>              <lgl>          <dbl>
 1 A     2022-11-01 00:00:00 FALSE              3
 2 A     2022-11-01 02:00:00 FALSE              1
 3 A     2022-11-01 03:00:00 TRUE               0
 4 A     2022-11-01 04:00:00 FALSE              1
 5 A     2022-11-01 05:00:00 TRUE               0
 6 A     2022-11-01 06:00:00 FALSE              1
 7 A     2022-11-01 09:00:00 FALSE              4
 8 A     2022-11-01 11:00:00 FALSE              6
 9 B     2022-11-01 00:00:00 FALSE              5
10 B     2022-11-01 01:00:00 FALSE              4
11 B     2022-11-01 02:00:00 FALSE              3
12 B     2022-11-01 05:00:00 TRUE               0
13 B     2022-11-01 06:00:00 FALSE              1
14 B     2022-11-01 07:00:00 FALSE              2
15 B     2022-11-01 10:00:00 TRUE               0
16 B     2022-11-01 12:00:00 FALSE              2
```

Answer (score 2):

A **base R** solution using the `apply` function family. First `split` the set by groups, then compare all dates with *indicator == TRUE* dates, then pick the `min`.

```
cbind(df, diff_hours = unlist(lapply(split(df, df$group), function(grp)
  apply(sapply(grp[grp$indicator == T, "date"], function(date_T) 
    abs(difftime(date_T, grp$date, u = "hour"))), 1, min))))
   group                date indicator diff_hours
A1     A 2022-11-01 01:00:00     FALSE          3
A2     A 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE          1
A3     A 2022-11-01 04:00:00      TRUE          0
A4     A 2022-11-01 05:00:00     FALSE          1
A5     A 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE          0
A6     A 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE          1
A7     A 2022-11-01 10:00:00     FALSE          4
A8     A 2022-11-01 12:00:00     FALSE          6
B1     B 2022-11-01 01:00:00     FALSE          5
B2     B 2022-11-01 02:00:00     FALSE          4
B3     B 2022-11-01 03:00:00     FALSE          3
B4     B 2022-11-01 06:00:00      TRUE          0
B5     B 2022-11-01 07:00:00     FALSE          1
B6     B 2022-11-01 08:00:00     FALSE          2
B7     B 2022-11-01 11:00:00      TRUE          0
B8     B 2022-11-01 13:00:00     FALSE          2
```